# Remove oldest N elements from document array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document in my mongodb that contains a very large array (about 10k items). I'm trying to only keep the latest 1k in the array (and so remove the first 9k elements). The document looks something like this:

```
    {
        "_id" : 'fakeid64',
        "Dropper" : [
            {
                "md5" : "fakemd5-1"
            },
            {
                "md5" : "fakemd5-2"
            },
            ...,
            {
                "md5": "fakemd5-10000"
            }
        ]
    }
```

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5):

The correct operation to do here actually involves the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator using the [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) and [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifiers. The usage may initially appear counter-intuitive that you would use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to "remove" items from an array, but the actual use case is clear when you see the intended operation.

```js
db.collection.update(
  { "_id": "fakeid64" },
  { "$push": { "Dropper": { "$each": [], "$slice": -1000 } }
)
```

You can in fact just run for your whole collection as:

```js
db.collection.update(
  { },
  { "$push": { "Dropper": { "$each": [], "$slice": -1000 } },
  { "multi": true }
)
```

What happens here is that the modifier for `$each` takes an array of items to "add" in the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operation, which in this case we leave empty since we do not actually want to add anything. The [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier given a "negative" value is actually saying to keep the "last n" elements present in the array as the update is performed, which is exactly what you are asking.

The general "intended" case is to use [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) when adding new elements to "maintain" the array at a "maximum" given length, which in this case would be 1000. So you would generally use in tandem with actually "adding" new items like this:

```js
db.collection.update(
  { "_id": "fakeid64" },
  { "$push": { "Dropper": { "$each": [{ "md5": "fakemd5-newEntry"}], "$slice": -1000 } }
)
```

This would append the new item(s) provided in `$each` whilst also removing any items from the "start" of the array where the total length given the addition was greater than 1000.

---

It is stated incorrectly elsewhere that you would use [`$pullAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) with a supplied list of the array content already existing in the document, but the operation is actually two requests to the database.

The misconception being that the request is sent as "one", but it actually is not and is basically interpreted as the longer form ( with correct usage of [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example) ):

```js
var md5s = db.collection.findOne({ "_id": "fakeid64" }).Dropper.slice(-1000);

db.collection.update(
  { "_id": "fakeid64" },
  { "$pullAll": { "Dropper": md5s } }
)
```

So you can see that this is not very efficient and is in fact quite **dangerous** when you consider that the state of the array within the document "could" possibly change in between the "read" of the array content and the actual "write" operation on update since they occur separately.

This is why MongoDB has atomic operators for [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) with [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) as is demonstrated. Since it is not only more efficient, but also takes into consideration the actual "state" of the document being modified at the time the actual modification occurs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [$pullAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) operator 
suppose you use python/pymongo driver:

```
yourcollection.update_one(
 {'_id': fakeid64}, 
 {'$pullAll': {'Dropper': yourcollection.find_one({'_id': 'fakeid64'})['Dropper'][:9000]}}
)
```

or in mongo shell:

```
db.yourcollection.update(
  { _id: 'fakeid64'}, 
  {$pullAll: {'Dropper': db.yourcollection.findOne({'_id' : 'fakeid64'})['Dropper'].slice(0,9000)}}
)
```

(*) having saying that it would be much better if you didn't allow your document(s) to grow this much in first place

Comment: This is a very incorrect statement since what is "actually" happening here involves "two" requests to the database. It is a common misconception that something like the `.findOne()` statement here is sent as part of the `.update()` operation, and this is not correct. In fact the correct operation here actually uses `$push`, as is stated in the [answer I have provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511145/2313887)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a representation of query. Basically you can unwind with limit and skip, then use cursor foreach to remove the items like below :

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
    { $match : { _id : 'fakeid64' } },
    { $unwind : "$Dropper"},
    { $skip : 1000},
    { $limit : 9000}
]).forEach(function(doc){
    db.your_collection.update({ _id : doc._id}, { $pull : { Dropper : doc.Dropper} }); 
});
```

Comment: you are doing in in a wrong way, @IsaacBok is asking for delete last 9K, not first 9K

Comment: @AlokDeshwal Both the answers here were wrong. The correct way to "remove" actually uses the `$push` operator, as explained in the [answer I have provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511145/2313887)

Answer (score 0):

from mongo docs

```js
db.students.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
        scores: {
           $each: [ { attempt: 3, score: 7 }, { attempt: 4, score: 4 } ],
           $sort: { score: 1 },
           $slice: -3
        }
     }
   }
)
```

The following update uses the $push operator with:

the $each modifier to append to the array 2 new elements,
the $sort modifier to order the elements by ascending (1) score, and
the $slice modifier to keep the last 3 elements of the ordered array.